# Filter by subarray

Tags: arrays, sqlalchemy

How can I use SQLAlchemy to filter on a column for a subarray?  I.e. the equivalent of doing this in Postgres:

```
select * from my_table where points[1:2] = ARRAY['A', 'B'];
```

My naive attempt was to do:

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.points[:2] == ['A', 'B']).all()
```

but that returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same slice in the filter as in sql

```
filter(MyTable.points[1:2] == ['A', 'B'])
```